# Question about spacing in .ttf fonts for android

Tags: fonts

I've been having trouble setting up a font to work well on my phone. I'm using an app that allows me to load ttf files into my system, the problem is spacing between lines/titles being too large (see attached screenshots).

I'm trying to figure out how to edit the ttf on font forge to resolve this, but it's been to no avail.

[image: new ttf font]

[image: Default font]